# Splitting Database does not bring over form (only table)

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I split my current database because it will be used by more than one group. When split, it brought over my main table, but no forms. I tried to re-create a form and drag/drop the form (from the original db) onto the new (split) database, but it does not allow it.

Is splitting the database the wrong route that I am taking in regards to what I am looking for?

Comment: Splitting should produce a BackEnd file of only tables and the splitted App file should contain all else objects. Check that **two** .mdb/.accdb files are in folder.

Comment: @Parfait Only the accdb file is in the folder

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Who needs to use which parts?

Comment: How did you split? With the icon on Access ribbon? That wizard creates a _be file.

Comment: @ashleedawg I  want to my split database to hold a table that can not be edited (which is already the case) and have a form that they can use to search records within that table (that form is already created in the original database).

Comment: @Parfait I used the "Access Database" button. The icon has 3 databases with two arrows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are yo sure that splitting is what you need to do?

From [Office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-an-access-database-3015ad18-a3a1-4e9c-a7f3-51b1d73498cc):

> When you split a database, you reorganize it into **two files**:
>
> - a back-end database that contains the data tables, and,
> - a front-end database that contains all the other database objects such as queries, forms, and reports.
>
> Each user interacts with the data by using a local copy of the front-end database.
>
> To split a database, you use the **Database Splitter Wizard**. After you split the database, you must distribute the front-end database to your users.

*Also*,

- **Everyone who uses the database must have a version** of Access that is compatible with the file format of the back-end database. For example, if the back-end database file uses the `.accdb` file format, users cannot access its data by using Access 2003.
- Before you begin, make a copy of the database that you want to split. Start with the database file on your local hard drive, **not on the network share**. If the database file is currently shared from your local hard disk drive, you can leave it where it is.
- The front-end database is **the file that you started with** (the copy of the original shared database), and the back-end database is located in **the network location that you specified** during the split process.

---

## The FE/BE Relationship

There may be confusion over the "term" back-end and front-end.

> It's not wrong of the client to refer to the admin side as back-end. It's actually fairly common terminology to call any aspects of a content management system that aren't publicly available the "back end." This confusion between the front and back end of a CMS and the front and back end of [a database] may be a large part of the problem you're encountering.   ([Source](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/38911/109180))

<sup><sub>(Click to Enlarge.)</sub></sup>
[image: FE-BE Relationship]

### *Perhaps a better way to think of it is to give the parts different names:*

<del>Front-End</del>    ➡   **User Portal**  <sub>(Multiple simultaneous users o.k.)</sub>

<del>Front-End</del>    ➡   **Management Portal**  <sub>(like a User Portal, with extra stuff)</sub>

<del>Back-End</del>         ➡   **Data Bank**  <sub>(Nobody accesses it except Access)</sub>

Comment: this is the feature I used. The split database only has a non-editable table. It did not give me options to bring over any forms. I need to bring over one of the forms.

Comment: You're not understanding the front-end/back-end relationship.  First off, you figured out that there are two files, right?  The back-end doesn't need a form, and you don't need to modify the table.  **Don't even open the back-end; forget it's there.**  Nobody interacts directly with the back-end. All the forms, queries and reports go in the front end.  Everyone interacts with the front-end.  The back-end only stores data, in such a way that multiple users can access it simultaneously.  Do whatever you need to do through a copy of the front-end.  Make all the copies of the front-end you want.

Comment: @KKP Let me know if you have any questions...  there's a definite learning-curve when first getting into multi-user database environments, especially one built from scratch.... and you've officially promoted yourself from DB-Dev to DB-Admin; you should get a raise. :-)  ...I remember the days well, lost a lot of hair (since there was no [so]!)

Comment: This comment made me smile! Thank you for your help and lending hand. I will reach out with any questions. Ahh I bet, a bit spoiled over here with the help we get from Stack Overflow.